# How to get a List of Maps from a List of Objects in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need some help with Scala. I really have troubles in understanding how to deal with collections. What I have to do is traversing a List like this

```
List( MyObject(id, name, status), ..., MyObject(id, name, status) )
```

and getting another List like this one

```
List( Map("key", id1), Map("key", id2), ..., Map("key", idN) )
```

Notice that the 'key' element of all the maps have to be the same

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the **map** function to transform a list of **MyObject** to a list of **Map** by:

```
val list = List( MyObject(id, name, status), ..., MyObject(id, name, status) )
val result = list map {o => Map("key" -> o.id)}
```

[scala school](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html) from twitter is a good reading for beginners, and if you want to know the architecture of the Scala collections framework in detail, please refer to [scala doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)

Comment: Will that work? Doesn't map need to take in a function that returns something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
list map { x => Map( "key" -> x.id ) }
```

An example

```
scala> case class Tst (fieldOne : String, fieldTwo : String)
defined class Tst

scala> val list = List(Tst("x", "y"), Tst("z", "a"))
list: List[Tst] = List(Tst(x,y), Tst(z,a))

list map { x => Map( "key" -> x.fieldOne ) }
res6: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(key -> y), Map(key -> a))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! It was so simple... My mistake was using a comma between the key and the value instead of the "arrow" symbol, that's why the compiler got angry!!